# 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'pk'

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a model that looks like this

```
class Connections(models.Model):
    following = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name='following'
    )
    followers = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name='followers'
    )
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, %s' % (self.following.username, self.followers.username)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('following', 'followers'), )
```

And then in TastyPie I am using the following code to extract the following users

```
class ConnectionsResource(ModelResource):
    user_following = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'following')
    user_follower = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'followers')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Connections.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'connections'

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return[
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('connections'), name="api_connections"),
        ]

    def connections(self,request,**kwargs):
        if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated():
            #Scribble Comments
            if request.GET.get('followers', ''):
                user = request.user
                followers = [connections.following for connections in user.followers.all()]
                followers_count = 1
                if followers_count > 0:
                    paginator = Paginator(followers, 20)
                    try:
                        page = paginator.page(int(request.GET.get('page', 1)))
                    except InvalidPage:
                        return self.create_response(request, { 'success': False, 'reason':'no more pages' })
                    objects = []
                    for result in page.object_list:
                        bundle = self.build_bundle(obj=result, request=request)
                        bundle = self.full_dehydrate(bundle)
                        objects.append(bundle)
                    followers_list = {
                    'followers_count': followers_count,
                    'followers' : objects,
                    'success': True,
                    }
                    self.log_throttled_access(request)
                    return self.create_response(request, followers_list)
                else:
                    return self.create_response(request, { 'success': False, 'reason':'No Followers' })
            else:
                return self.create_response(request, { 'success': False, 'reason':'Wrong Query'})
        else:
            return self.create_response(request, { 'success': False, 'reason':'User not Logged in'})

    def determine_format(self, request):
        return 'application/json'
```

But I keep on getting the `'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'pk'` error. I am not sure why

Traceback:

```
traceback: "Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/Users/jonathan/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 202, in wrapper response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs) 
File "/Users/jonathan/virtualenvs/myproject/bin/django_worksquid/scribbler/api.py", line 547, in connections bundle = self.full_dehydrate(bundle) 
File "/Users/jonathan/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 837, in full_dehydrate bundle.data[field_name] = field_object.dehydrate(bundle) 
File "/Users/jonathan/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py", line 729, in dehydrate return self.dehydrate_related(fk_bundle, self.fk_resource) 
File "/Users/jonathan/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py", line 557, in dehydrate_related return related_resource.get_resource_uri(bundle) 
File "/Users/jonathan/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 784, in get_resource_uri return self._build_reverse_url(url_name, kwargs=self.resource_uri_kwargs(bundle_or_obj)) 
File "/Users/jonathan/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 763, in resource_uri_kwargs kwargs.update(self.detail_uri_kwargs(bundle_or_obj)) 
File "/Users/jonathan/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 2371, in detail_uri_kwargs kwargs[self._meta.detail_uri_name] = getattr(bundle_or_obj.obj, self._meta.detail_uri_name) AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'pk' "
```

## Edit

When I changed `followers_count = 1` to `followers_count = followers.count()` it gives me

```
"count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)"  error
```

## Edit

I finally realized that followers is a list not an object, so I changed my code a bit to

```
def connections(self,request,**kwargs):
    if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated():
        #Scribble Comments
        if request.GET.get('followers', ''):
            user = request.user
            followers = [connections.following for connections in user.followers.all()]
            users_id = [s.id for s in followers]
            users=User.objects.filter(id__in = users_id)
            users_count = users.count()
            users_list = {
            'users_count': users_count,
            'users' : users,
            'success': True,
            }
            return self.create_response(request, users_list)
        else:
            return self.create_response(request, { 'success': False, 'reason':'Wrong Query'})
    else:
        return self.create_response(request, { 'success': False, 'reason':'User not Logged in'})
```

Now I do get the output, but I get it in terms of objects, like

```
success: true,
users: "[<User: abc>, <User: test>, <User: abc2>, <User: test2>]",
users_count: 4
```

Instead of this, I want my object to show the email addresses and all of the user instead of just this object.

Comment: Can you include a stack trace with the rest of the error message?

Comment: @Ric please have a look at the edit

Comment: For the principle I quite agree with Ric, I don’t understand why it doesn’t work with his answer.
However with your `followers_count` problem you should do something like `followers_count = sum([query.count() for query in followers])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was easy. It turs out, that I was supposed to use `ToManyField` for User objects not `ForeignKey`, and that fixed everything!

Answer (score 0):

`'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'pk'` probably means TastyPie was expecting an object but instead you gave it a `RelatedManager` which is like `connections.following` I would make sure that `result` in `for result in page.object_list` is an object, you may need to iterate through all the `connections.following` users.

```
for result in page.object_list:
    print result
    for following_user in result.all():
        print following_user
        bundle = self.build_bundle(obj=following_user, request=request)
        bundle = self.full_dehydrate(bundle)
        objects.append(bundle)
```

Also have you considered just using a [ManyToMany field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) either by also have a `Profile` model that has a OneToOne relationship with the User or upgrading to Django 1.5 which allows [extending the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)? That way instead of implementing your own ManyToMany relationship, you can use all the benefits of Django's built-in one such as just saying `user.followers.all()` and getting all the users that are following that user.

Something like this would work for extracting the information

```
users = [{
             'email': u.email, 
             'name': u.name,
             ...
         } for u in User.objects.filter(id__in = users_id)]
```

Although you should probably try using `build_bundle` as well

```
users = [self.full_dehydrate(self.build_bundle(obj=u, request=request)) 
         for u in User.objects.filter(id__in = users_id)]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening either, sorry.

Comment: @Jonathan Please take a look at my new answer.

Comment: that doesnt seem to work either. also, since result is supposed to be a user object, how would result.all() work? as its just one object. also, please look at my edit

Comment: Also, people who are voting down this answer, it'll be highly appreciated if you answer the question if you know what is going on, instead of voting someone else's efforts down.

Comment: Can you post the output with the print statements in my answer and the error? Is the exception on the full_dehydrate included in my answer?

Comment: `followers.count()` should probably be `len(followers)`

Comment: Not sure what the -1 was for, this has fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can help with at one issue:

```
followers = [connections.following for connections in user.followers.all()]
```

You can't call `.count()` on that, because you're putting the results of your query into a list. Use `len(followers)` or `User.objects.get(following__followers=user)`.

The rest of the code is pretty odd, but I can't see a sure issue with it either. Perhaps the issue is in `UserResource`? You'll probably want to look at line 837.